# PHP appending a weird value to my variable when it is POSTed through an input form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an input form-

```
<input type="hidden" name="unsubscribe_email" value="<?=$email;?>" />
```

The variable `$email` is a decrypted one, & it holds the value `psb@***.com` (when echoed in the same page).

I'm retrieving the value in my action page like- `$_POST['unsubscribe_email']`.

Instead of getting `***@***.com`, the variable is getting appended.

This is what I get

`psb@***.comï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½`

I'm clueless as to why this is happening.

Here's the actual code-
HTML-

```
<form method="POST" name="some_name" action="my_page.php">
<input type="hidden" name="unsubscribe_email" value="<?=$email;?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Unsubscribe" />
</form>
```

PHP-

```
$email = $_POST['unsubscribe_email'];
echo $email; //gives me this-   psb@*.comï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
```

EDIT: The decrypt method that I'm using is appending "\u000" to the original string.

Any leads on how to deal with "\u000"?

Thanks in advance, folks!

Comment: Post the relevant HTML and PHP?

Comment: Added a piece of code there.

Comment: use `trim` may be it can help.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to work, Junaid!

Comment: At a guess it looks like a character encoding problem, maybe the answer on this question will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1920881/1017963

Comment: Here is what i would do: use Firefox+firebug and verify what values are you sending. Maybe you already have binary data into that variable so you post them as they are. Also you can verify (and add here ) the headers sent with the request. Their encoding is also a clue, as it may be different than the Content-type you put.

Comment: Warning: Try setting the email to `"><script>alert("Owned.")</script><b`

Answer (score 0):

It may be the encoding issue. Set meta tag with charset="utf-8".

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: I have already added it, & it's not helping.
I have edited the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Post the variable as a text to your page an make sure the encoding is wrong in the $_POST and not on the first email variable generated.

```
<form method="POST" name="some_name" action="my_page.php">
<input type="hidden" name="unsubscribe_email" value="<?=$email;?>" />
<?php echo $email; ?>
<input type="submit" value="Unsubscribe" />
</form>
```

Comment: Rich, the encoding is wrong in the first email variable generated.
The decrypt method that I'm using is appending "\u000" to the original variable.